# svn merge says absolutely everything conflicts

Tags: svn

I tried to synch my trunk changes into my branch using "svn merge" but subversion says that every single file has a conflict.  Most of those files weren't changed in either trunk or branch.  I didn't change the directory structure either.  What am I doing wrong?

In more detail, I'm in the branch on my computer, at /Users/steve/myproject/nsvbranch.  I enter "svn merge https://myserver.org/users/steve/myproject/trunk".  That's the trunk version of the same directory as nsvbranch; "ls" returns the same files in the two cases.  The server takes a little time, and then lists absolutely every single file with a "C" next to it.  For several of them, but not all, it asks me how I want to deal with the conflict.  In nearly all of the files, including several where it asked me about how to deal with the conflicts, no changes were made in either the trunk or the branch since the branch was made.

I'm clearly making a very simple beginner error, but I can't seem to figure out what it is.  Thanks for any help!

-Steve

Comment: What is version of SVN server and SVN client?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm using server version 1.4.2 and client version 1.6.18. -Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help.  Given that I can't update the server subversion to a current version, I entered the revision numbers.  It turned out that merging was quite easy this way.  I looked back in the log to find where the branch was made and then entered "merge -r2050:2121 https://myserver.org/users/steve/myproject/trunk".  Then it happened as it should.

-Steve

Answer (score 0):

The most probable reason is that SVN incorrectly selects range of revisions to merge.

Version 1.4 of SVN has very weak merging support. I would recommend to update SVN if you are going to merge regularly.

If you decide to continue use SVN 1.4, you have to manually specify range of revisions when you merge.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using version 1.4 any more. There was a major change in Subversion 1.5 that added merge tracking into Subversion. In fact, I'm surprised no one has setup a pre-commit trigger on your system to prevent you from committing code modified with version 1.4.

Since you're using Subversion 1.4, there might be other issues at play. For example, you can't tell what was merged and what wasn't. In Subversion before 1.5, you need to specify all revisions that you want to merge. Manually. The best way maybe to look for the property `svn:mergeinfo` and see what was merged:

```
$ svn propget -R svn:mergeinfo .
```

This will print out all merges and what revisions are merged. You can use this to figure out what revisions you need to merge. For example, if you see that you're on revision 2300, and the svn:mergeinfo says that revisions 1230-2298 have already been merged from that branch, you need to specify that you want to merge revisions 2299 to 2300:

```
$ svn merge -r2299:2300 $REPO/$branch/$project
```

Once you do that, you need to update `svn:mergeinfo` with the latest merge:

```
$ svn pe svn:mergeinfo .  #And all files/directories where this is set
```

The other possibility is someone deleted and recreated the branch/trunk. Imagine someone did this:

```
$ svn co $REPO/trunk/foo
A foo/bar.txt
A foo/foo.txt
$ cd foo
$ svn delete bar.txt
$ svn commit -m"Deleted bar.txt"
$ svn up
$ vi bar.txt
$ svn add bar.txt
$ svn commit -m"Added bar.txt back in"
```

To your mere mortal eyes, you think `$REPO/trunk/foo/bar.txt` is the same in both revisions. After all, they both have the URL `$REPO/trunk/foo/bar.txt`. To Subversion these two `bar.txt` are two completely different files and share nothing in common. If someone made a change in `$REPO/branches/1.2/foo/bar.txt` and you tried to merge this change, you'd get a merge conflict. In fact, the merge conflict would tell you that a *local add* is in the way of update.

I've see plenty of places that decide that trunk needs to match a branch, and they deleted the trunk, and copied the files over from the branch. In fact, I've seen this:

```
$ svn delete -m"Who needs trunk?" $REPO/trunk  #Delete trunk
$ svn add -m"Making a real mess of things" $REPO/trunk #Add a new trunk
$ svn co $REPO/trunk  # Check out the now empty trunk
$ cd trunk
$ cp -R $work/branches/1.4 .  #Copy a branch 1.4 working directory to trunk
$ svn add .  #Now add all of those files back in
$ svn commit -m"A trunk with files that aren't related to anything!"
```

In this case, not only did the developer delete trunk, but they simply created a new empty trunk, copied the files in behind Subversion's back, and then readded them back in. Every single file in trunk is completely unrelated to any file in your repository even though they share similar URLs. In this case, they also wanted to know why they couldn't merge back from the branch to trunk. After all, that's where the files were from?

If this was done, you're basically up a rather putrid estuary without any means of propulsion.

The only suggestion I could add is to try `svn merge --ignore-ancestory`. I also suggest you try the `--dry-run` parameter to see how the merge will happen without affecting anything.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I asked our tech guy about updating the server subversion and he said it's in process and will probably happen sometime this year.  I'm not holding my breath.  I'll try the alternate approaches next.  -Steve